# c# set PictureBox.BackroundColor to transparent even if there are more than one control below

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, background-color

I am trying to set the BackgroundColor of a PictureBox transparent. I know that this just copies the Foreground from the Control below to the Background to the Control on top. This works fine until I have more than just 1 control below.

Imagine I had a 4x4 PictureBox pBOverlay. On top of this overlay I want to put one single PictureBox pBonTop which has the height and width from the 4x4 Overlay. How can I set the Background to transparency? Is this even possible?

Comment: It is technically possible, the formatting of the code in [the KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943454/winforms-how-to-create-a-control-transparent-to-other-controls) is nicely wonky to discourage programmers from using it.  By far the best way to create layers of paint is with Graphics.DrawImage().

Comment: @HansPassant I was afraid of that there was no better solution than DrawImage(). I hoped that there was a faster solution. But thank you anyways!